# How to make PostgreSQL load "share" from a relative directory

Tags: postgresql, pg

The PostgreSQL Linux arm version always loads the `share` folder from the absolute directory `/usr/share/postgresql/<version>/`.

But the version provided on this web site for Windows & **Linux x64** binary doesn't (I've tested, it load from runtime's relative path), and unfortunately, there is no `Linux arm` version.

https://www.enterprisedb.com/download-postgresql-binaries

There also no runtime argument to use to make it work (I have already tried, the `-L` argument only works for setup, the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable only works for `lib` folder, NO argument works for `share` folder).

So I tried to compile from the source code and specify the `--datarootdir` option for the `./configure` command to customize this folder.

But this `./configure` argument is limited to being an absolute directory.

How can I make the PostgreSQL Linux arm version load `share` from a relative directory (from the current executing subdirectory)?